# Como trabalhar com rotas no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rotas

É possível trabalhar com rotas personalizadas dentro do wordpress?

Eu estou construindo um site que consome uma api onde o usuário poderá fazer buscas de produtos.

Eu gostaria de personalizar a url do site para determinas páginas da seguinte maneira meusite.com/estado/cidade/bairro/aqui_vem_o_meu_produto
essa url seria direcionada para uma página do wordpress.

att,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está procurando pela [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). Ela é usada pra personalizar as URLs de forma que você consiga buscar os valores dentro da sua query da forma que precisar.

Exemplo do [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule):

```
<?php
  function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    /**
     * add_rewrite_tag() cria "tags" que podem ser acessadas pelo 
     * objeto de query padrão, usando get_query_var()
     */
    add_rewrite_tag('%food%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%variety%', '([^&]+)');

    /**
     * add_rewrite_rule() cria regras para traduzir as queries em URLs
     * no formato desejado.
     *
     * A regra aqui cria a URL: http://example.com/nutrition/milkshakes/strawberry/
     * transformada em food=milkshakes e variety=strawberry
     */      
    add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
?>
```

Links:

[add_rewrite_rule()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

[add_rewrite_tag()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.